# Choosing The right hyperparameters when initial random seed is set

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, neural-network, hyperparameters

I have a simple model of 3 dense layers. In each layer, I would like to set the number of hidden nodes to be chosen from a list. Hence, for `dense_layer1` I have: `[16, 32, 64]`; for `dense_layer2` and `dense_layer3` I have  `[32, 64, 128]`.

Now since the weight initialization makes a difference in model training, I found that with the same model configurations, I may achieve some times an accuracy or 0.6, sometimes 0.7 and some times 0.725, after every training run (for 30 epochs). My first problem is that I have small dataset.

As a result, how can I chose between my model configurations if the result varies tremendously between alternative runs to my code, and to the same model configuration?

In other words, if we assume that the following model configuration is the best (unknown) model config that achieve the highest accuracy on the testing dataset:

```
model_config_1 = {'dense1': 32, 'dense2': 32, 'dense3': 64}
```

after several runs I get the following results (NOTE: Initial seed is not set in code):

```
run1: 0.625, run2: 0.65. run3: 0.75, run4: 0.55, run5: 0.675
```

And if the true second best (unknown) model is:

```
model_config_2 = {'dense1': 32, 'dense2': 32, 'dense3': 32}
```

after several runs I may get the following results:

```
run1: 0.625, run2: 0.6. run3: 0.725, run4: 0.5, run5: 0.7
```

Therefore, in order to correctly evaluate a model, I should train and test the **SAME** model 5 times. Thus, this will require a huge amount of time.

But if I set the initial seed, and (train and test) both models only 1 time, I may get `accuracy_model_1 = 0.675` and that of the second model: `accuracy_model_2 = 0.7`.

What should I do in this case, how to chose model 1 against model 2?

Please note that my models are tested in tensorflow and I guess the same problem could be faced with any other DNN framework.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Do you have to use a neural network, given you don't have that much data? The fact that your accuracy varies a lot between runs shows that neural networks might not be the best solution. Can't you use a simpler model to solve this (like a Logistic Regression model)?

Comment: @thushv89, do you mean that in general we shouldn't find huge difference in the accuracy on the testing dataset if we have sufficient dataset, after completely training a neural network?

Comment: Hey, well partially. If you feel like you're getting significantly different performance (this depends on the problem and the amount of data) between runs, that shouldn't usually happen if you have enough data to train a neural network.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you @thushv89, I would appreciate as well if you can provide me some evidence or resources about your suggestions/realization.

Comment: I can't recall any right now. But I'll have a look around. And another thing to make sure is use something like "early stopping" (if you can spare a validation set) to make sure the network is not under-performing.